# tag search statistics

Tags: discussion

I've been striking out tags that I think are null-content (e.g. "test", "testcase"), but I'm making that judgment without any kind of data.  Do we have per-tag search statistics?

> *If I know there are actually lots of searches for "testcase", I will have to reevaluate whether to strike it.*

Comment: I have not seen any search statistics yet. I think it's pretty safe to remove a lot of the obvious ones that would apply to every question and a lot of the tags with less than 10 questions.

Comment: I can't confirm that the stats don't exist, but I can confirm that if they do I don't know about them!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is the answer: the stats may or may not exist, but they are not accessible, and specifically they are not accessible to non-moderators.